# PHP Force Download Causing 0 Byte Files

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to force download files from my web server using PHP.
I'm not a pro in PHP but I just can't seem to get around the problem of files downloading in 0 bytes in size.

CODE:

```
$filename = "FILENAME...";

header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
set_time_limit(0);
readfile($file);
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the given file exists using that path and has some content?

Comment: Just a small note, but you should watch out for directory traversal. A potential attacker could use, for instance, "../../../../var/www/config.php" and may read some sensitive data.

Comment: any solution for this issue, facing same problem

Answer (score 9):

You're not checking that the file exists. Try using this:

```
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file))
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}else
{
    echo "File does not exists";
}
```

And see what you get.

---

You should also note that this forces a download as an octet stream, a plain binary file. Some browsers will struggle to understand the exact type of the file. If, for example, you send a GIF with a header of `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`, then the browser may not treat it like a GIF image. You should add in specific checks to determine what the content type of the file is, and send an appropriate `Content-Type` header.

Comment: This does work, I think you need extend your question with what browser your using, what the file is, where its located, the permissions of the file as well dir, and what server your running.

Comment: thanks for this. I had the 0 byte problem with ppt files only. The ob_clean() and flush() before the stream_get_contents() helped.

Comment: According to PHP site, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#102137      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));   
$file should really be the full path to the file.  Otherwise content length will not always be set, often resulting in the dreaded "0 byte file" problem. Or just try like this header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath)); First set path like this and it immediately worked for me and 0 BYTES problem solved!!!

Answer (score 4):

I use the following method in [phunction](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/) and I haven't had any issues with it so far:

```
function Download($path, $speed = null)
{
    if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        $file = @fopen($path, 'rb');
        $speed = (isset($speed) === true) ? round($speed * 1024) : 524288;

        if (is_resource($file) === true)
        {
            set_time_limit(0);
            ignore_user_abort(false);

            while (ob_get_level() > 0)
            {
                ob_end_clean();
            }

            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf('%u', filesize($path)));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

            while (feof($file) !== true)
            {
                echo fread($file, $speed);

                while (ob_get_level() > 0)
                {
                    ob_end_flush();
                }

                flush();
                sleep(1);
            }

            fclose($file);
        }

        exit();
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can try it simply by doing:

```
Download('/path/to/file.ext');
```

Comment: Nice little implementation to the throttling :)

Comment: -1 Throttling should be done by the server, not a PHP script. I think that this is bad style.

Comment: @Daniel: Just out of curiosity, how would you implement something like RapidShare then?

Comment: @Alex: Two questions, 1) does your file exists? 2) are you outputting anything else before (and/or are you using `ob_start()`)?

Comment: @Alix I am using ob_start and am calling on a database select/connect (before). Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel: Still, how would you limit the distribution speed?

Comment: @Danial we understand how throttling should be implemented but just because its implemented using PHP does not mean that its wrong, its just not the best method.

Comment: @Alex: What does your `$filename` variable hold? A BLOB from the database? If `$filename` is a valid filesystem path to a file and your database methods aren't throwing any errors this should work... What browser are you using?

Comment: @Alix I'm using Firefox, the $filename will return simply "filename.extension".

Comment: @Alex: I think that may be the problem... Try specifying the **absolute path** to the file, something like `$filename = 'C:/www/test.zip';`.

Comment: @Alix: If I wanted to create my own CDN, then I would set up a Squid cache with delay pools: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bandwidth-Limiting-HOWTO.html

Comment: @Alix Thanks for all the help so far, I'm not amazing at programming. Could you help me specify a specific path. Im using a web server that would look something like this: www/27/fileinhere (would I have to add anything else, like username?)

Comment: @Daniel: Nice. Squid cache looks awesome, I had no idea one could throttle B/W per user basis. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: Are you on Linux or Windows? Imagine that the absolute path to the `Letter.txt` file is `/home/user/docs/Letter.txt`, if your current working directory is `/home/user/` the relative path to the file is `./docs/Letter.txt` however the absolute path is always the same (`/home/user/docs/Letter.txt`) no matter where you are... This is kinda hard to explain clearly in a comment and I would have to know your filesystem structure to give you a specific answer, read this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) maybe it helps you.

Comment: @Alex: I think that Alix has identified the problem. It sounds as though `$filename` is the name that you want the browser to save the file as, but not the *path* to the actual file in the filesystem. I think that you need to give a more concrete example. What is a valid value of `$filename` and what is the exact path to the file in the filesystem?

Comment: Squid caches are used in most organizations as proxies and limiters, I think we use over 200 builds of squid across our company, we have to manage them on a daily basis and I still do not think the down vote was valid.

Comment: @Alex: Also be aware of [CWE-434](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/434.html) Unrestricted Upload of File with Dangerous Type.

Comment: remove `sleep(1);` for fast download.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the `Content-Length` header:

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
```

Also, you shouldn't send a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header. Both of the [HTTP/1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#MIME-CTE) and [HTTP/1.1 specs state](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.4.5) that "HTTP does not use the Content-Transfer-Encoding (CTE) field of RFC 1521".

Answer (score 2):

This problem as same as my website project. This code I've used:

```
<?php

$file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/.../.../'.$_GET['file'];

 if(!file)
 {
     // File doesn't exist, output error
     die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {

    //$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
    $file_extension = end(explode(".", $file));

    switch( $fileExtension)
    {
    case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
    case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    nocache_headers();

     // Set headers
    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public"); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));

     readfile($file);
 }
 ?>
```

I think the problem is on the server setting like PHP setting or cache setting, but I don't have any idea to do this my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

i am doing this to download a PDF ...

```
$filename = 'Application.pdf';
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $pdf;
```

i think you are missing the last row, where you actually send the file contents of whatever you have in `$file`.

Pablo

Answer (score 0):

The file opened ok for me when I changed the directory to the file location.

```
$reportLocation = REPORTSLOCATION;

$curDir = getcwd();

chdir($reportLocation);

if (file_exists($filename)) {

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile($filename);
}
chdir($curDir);
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to check with file_exists to confirm the correct path.
The big confusion is that for PHP paths you don't need to start with '/' to say your website start path.

```
 '/folder/file.ext'  #bad, needs to know the real full path
```

in php / is the website main path already, you don't need to mention it. Just:

```
 'folder/file.ext'   #relative to the / website
```

This will work with file_exists,  header filename, readfile, etc...

Answer (score 0):

if script work work for small files but for huge files return 0 byte file. you must increate memory_limit via php.ini
also you can add the following line before your code

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
```