# Header php force download 'remember this' checkbox disabled

Tags: php, download, header

I have this function working fine to force a download but I was asking me why is the checkbox "Do this automatically for file like this from now on" disabled. My idea is to let open or download without asking.

```
function Download($path, $speed = null)
{
    if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        $file = @fopen($path, 'rb');
        $speed = (isset($speed) === true) ? round($speed * 1024) : 524288;

        if (is_resource($file) === true)
        {
            set_time_limit(0);
            ignore_user_abort(false);

            while (ob_get_level() > 0)
            {
                ob_end_clean();
            }

            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf('%u', filesize($path)));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

            while (feof($file) !== true)
            {
                echo fread($file, $speed);

                while (ob_get_level() > 0)
                {
                    ob_end_flush();
                }

                flush();
                sleep(1);
            }

            fclose($file);
        }

        exit();
    }

    return false;
}
```

This function comes from this post:
[PHP Force Download Causing 0 Byte Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706073/php-force-download-causing-0-byte-files)

Im using firefox 54.0 (64-bit) on ubuntu 16.04

Thanks!

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== false` and `!== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant. In this case, `while (!feof($file))` is sufficient.

Comment: Ok, done.As I said I copied this function but didnt think could be better in the way you say. But still dont understand if something in the header can unlock the checkbox!?